# How to unmarshal nested dynamic xml without xsd?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm able to unmurshal a single occurrence of a dynamic xml instantiating java classes (a wrapper and an adapter), but I don't understand how to extend this mechanism to a list of occurrences; the xml is like

```
<ALLRECORDSDATASET>
  <RECORD>
    <FIELD_0001>000248031</FIELD_0001>
    <FIELD_0022>A</FIELD_0022>
    <FIELD_0031>0</FIELD_0031>
    <FIELD_0033>1994-01-01</FIELD_0033>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <FIELD_0001>000248056</FIELD_0001>
    <FIELD_0027>ABC</FIELD_0027>
    <FIELD_0037>DEF</FIELD_0037>
    <FIELD_0040>1994-01-01</FIELD_0040>
  </RECORD>
</ALLRECORDSDATASET>
```

and I can get the last values of RECORD (having a Record class containing a Fields class using @XmlAnyElement annotation), but I can't get all the RECORD list.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats one way of doing that

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ALLRECORDSDATASET")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class DataSet {

    @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "RECORD", type = Record.class) })
    private List<Record> records;

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Record {

    @XmlElement(name = "FIELD_0001")
    private String field;
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks k5 but unfortunately the fields in records often changes; I can have FIELD_0001.. FIELD_9999 so I have to translate them in a list of elements of a generic Class (that have a Wrapper and an Adapter)